# Access 2010 Calculate Crash on column addition

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am doing a calculate field in a table in access 2010.  A column being the total is adding up to 24 other columns.  I either get no return or it will crash.

I have the following in the expression builder that gives no return
[Column1]+[Column2]+[Column3]+[Column4]+[Column5]... etc

If I add an = as below, access will crash.
=[Column1]+[Column2]+[Column3]+[Column4]+[Column5]... etc

Note, both do not literally include '... etc' I just did not want to clog up the question with the column names.

I would like this to return the values of the columns being added together and totaled up.  What is missing or required for this?

Comment: Just a tip, you should state the goal you are trying to achieve instead of asking non-questions like `Am I missing something very obvious here?` because it tends to mean you don't get answers at all.

Comment: You should probably be trapping for nulls in the columns being added together. Maybe NZ function or IIF combined with IsNull